# Sequential term patterns - python - text mining

Tags: python, algorithm, data-mining, text-mining, apriori

I'm trying to discover some term patterns in a text. I'm looking for rules of this kind:
"hello" is followed by "world" with a confidence "0.2" and a lift "0.8"

I know that for this kind of patterns I can use **sequential algorithms**, like GSP Algorithm o CSPADE. I have use those algorithms in R in other projects with not so much success.

Has anyone developed this in python and could help me with some more information.

Thank you all in advance! :)

Comment: What is the question exactly? You seem to have a clue how to do it, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I know what I need **sequential pattern algorithm**, what i'm asking for is some documentation about how to implement it in pyhton